# How to set a react native listview datasource based on a Firebase query and keep the real-time updates

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to flatten my data structure so I have Flights, and inside Users I have a node called currentTrip, which contains the ID for all the flights a person has in a current trip.  The Id maps to the Id of the flight in Flights.

If I was just querying Flights, I can get the datasource set and it will continue to update the listview perfectly as the data changes.

But since I'm trying to flatten, I can't seem to find the right spot to set the new datasource.  If I set it where I expect, it gets set before any of the flights are finished adding to a flights array.  If I set it directly after a new flight is pushed to the array, then each new change results in a whole new copy of the flight being added.  I hesitate to use .once because I want the data to remain fresh and real-time.

Here is the code for the FB piece.  This is within a React Native project.  I'm sure I'm just thinking too synchronously.

```
 listenForItems(tripRef) {
    var flightRef = this.getRef().child('flights')
    var tripSegments = [];
    var flights = [];

    tripRef.on('value', (snap) => {  
      // Create a list of Trip Segments

      snap.forEach((child) => {
         // For each segment, get the ID and then go get the flight details
          var indFlightRef = flightRef.child(child.val().legId);

              indFlightRef.on('value', (snap) => { 
                flights.push({
                  departureAir: snap.val().depAir,
                  _key: child.key
                });

              });
      });
        // In a synchronous world I would expect to set the new datasource here
        this.setState({
                    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(flights)
        });          
  }); 
}
```

Any nudge in the right direction would be awesome. Thanks.

**UPDATE EDIT:**  If I setState directly after flights.push my initial ListView is perfect. If I expect 2 rows, I see the two rows. However... if the data changes in any of the existing nodes, it won't simply update the corresponding row in the ListView, it will add a whole new row.

Comment: Doing some more research on flat structures and considering saving a reference to the flight in both user node and flights node. This would allow me to filter flights.flight.users.UID. Which "could" work but I feel like performance would suffer as we get thousands of flight records.

Comment: Perhaps you can prevent unnecessary render by using `componentWillUpdate` ?

Comment: @Xeijp Interesting. Are you suggesting I check the current datasource in state against the nextState datasource? That could work to eliminate the extra row. But I'm not sure that addresses what is likely a flaw in my data structure design or implementation. Simpler queries perform perfectly. But it seems having to loop is causing issues.